# Como executar um comando via proc_open e não aguardar o término da execução?

Tags: php

Possuo um projeto Symfony2 que gera um PDF a partir de um HTML com o bundle `KnpSnappyBundle`, que tem como dependência o bundle `KnpSnappy` e que, por sua vez, faz a abstração com o executável `wkhtmltopdf`.

Esse binário é executado com os devidos parâmetros por meio da função `proc_open` do PHP conforme linha abaixo:

```
$process = proc_open($this->command, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, $this->env);
```

Nos testes que fiz, notei que o processo fica preso ao processo do Apache. Logo, se o servidor estiver sobrecarregado, a resposta do Apache pode demorar muito, o que não é uma opção.

Trocar a função também ou a funcionalidade do bundle também não é uma opção. As únicas coisas que posso fazer são modificar os parâmetros da função `proc_open` de modo que o processo não fique preso ao Apache – isso se essa opção existir.

Alguém já fez algo do tipo ou conhece algum workaround?

Comment: Olha, já passei por esse problema também, um workaround que eu fiz na época, foi utilizar um proc_open em um SSH e executar o comando que eu desejava no SSH atribuindo o processo ao background, em seguida desconectando. Mas é uma gambiarra daquelas. Porém funciona, até porque eu estava levantando serviços e não dava pra deixar minha aplicação pendurada neles.

Comment: @GabrielGartz a solução que achei seria colocar um `&` ao final do comando, mas como processo de geração está bastante encapsulado, não tenho como fazer isso.

Comment: É o problema de usar o & no final, que vc roda em background mas o processo fica atrelado a quem o disparou, isso é, se você matar o processo do PHP (que tende a terminar no fim do script) ele vai parar o processo pendurado e se este não tiver terminado, vai ser cancelado.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu tive um problema similar e resolvi utilizando um sistema de queue e colocando o script para rodar de forma assíncrona.

Dá uma olhada no [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) e veja como é simples de utilizar: [GearmanClient::doBackground](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/gearmanclient.dobackground.php)

Comment: Realmente o Gearman resolve para alguns casos mas no meu caso específico eu preciso que funcione de acordo com os parâmetros que eu passar para o `proc_open`.